# In multiple Y axis graph, the axis shift issue in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, charts

I have chart control,depends upon the selection i have to plot a graph,here is screen shot

[image]

[image]

First case i have selected, 2 inputs and second case  given 1 input. as above images it shifts axis.If i refresh it will be the proper position.

```
         <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" 
                                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding MaxX}" Title="Time (Minutes)"  />
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  Title="Oxygen" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" Visibility="{Binding O2.GraphVisibility}"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding O2.TGraph,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0"   >
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource graphO2}"/>
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Title="{Binding O2.YTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource graphO2}" Visibility="{Binding O2.YVisibility}" Maximum="{Binding O2.MaxY}" Orientation="Y" Location="{Binding O2.YLocation}" />
                </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>

            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
 </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Using WPF Toolkit Data Visualization for graph.Please help me solve this issue.Coding side using MVVM architecuture.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that chart doesn't refreshe in proper way, when you change input or modify dependency properties.

At least in [LightningChart Visualization component](http://arction.com/), you can disable chart rendering - modify properties - continue rendering. You can easily prevent such bugs.

Try that and see the result. It has free demoapp with examples and available code. Can help you.